# Getting an error while deploying smart contracts, Cannot read property 'deployed' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

Im making a frontend for a Dapp, so after making instances of the smart contracts and setting a provider I try to deploy the contract, get the token balance  and display it in on the web page but get the error:

> Cannot read property 'deployed' of undefined

in my browser.

Note that my FixedSupplyToken.sol is deployed on test RPC as I can see in the FixedSupplyToken.json file, it has an address. Was thinking this was the issue, but no such luck.

```
app.js:

    // Import libraries we need.
    import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
    import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
    
    // Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
    import exchange_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/Exchange.json'
    import token_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/FixedSupplyToken.json'
    
    
    var accounts;
    var account;
    
    var ExchangeContract = contract(exchange_artifacts);
    var TokenContract = contract(token_artifacts);
    window.App = {
      start: function() {
       //bootstrap everything
       
       ExchangeContract = web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
       TokenContract = web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

},

 //update balance function

 updateTokenBalance: function() {
    var tokenInstance;
    **TokenContract.deployed().then(function (instance) { // getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deployed' of undefined**
        tokenInstance = instance;
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf.call(account);
    }).then(function (value) {
        
        var balance_element = document.getElementById("balanceTokenInToken");
        balance_element.innerHTML = value.valueOf();
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        App.setStatus("Error getting balance; see log.");
    });
  },
```

[image]

So I have tried :
[image]

[image]

Even if I uncomment `web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)` I get the setProvider undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `start` function, you're reassigning the `TokenContract` variable.

Try changing

```
ExchangeContract = web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
TokenContract = web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```

to:

```
ExchangeContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
TokenContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```

Edit based on comment:

The root of the problem is that `web3.setProvider` method returns void or `undefined`, so in the statement `TokenContract = web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);` you are assigning `undefined` to `TokenContract`, hence the error. Setting the web3 provider and the Truffle contract provider are two different actions. Not sure if there's more code in the `//bootstrap everything` but if for some reason you need to set the provider explicitly try changing the code to:

```
web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
ExchangeContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
TokenContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```

The first line, though, shouldn't be necessary if Web3 is configured correctly. I suggest reading this article for this since there's been changes in how this is done: https://medium.com/@awantoch/how-to-connect-web3-js-to-metamask-in-2020-fee2b2edf58a.

The gist of it is:

```
window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
window.ethereum.enable();
```

Comment: Ceno , well Im migrating my contracts to ganache and then injecting metamask in my chrome. When I was using set.provider(web3.currentProvider)  I was getting set.provider not defined , so I googled it and found that someone had the same issue and they resolved it by using web3.setProvider...

Comment: Hi. I added a more detailed explanation based on your comment.

Comment: I have updated my post based on your comment. As far I can understand upon reading the link you provided is that we set the current provider with window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum), then contract = setProvider(web3.currentProvider) should work ? But I still get the setProvider undefined error... :/

Comment: Notice that it should be `TokenContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);`, not `TokenContract = setProvider(web3.currentProvider);` I would like to also point to Truffle Contract's repository for further detail: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract

Comment: Yes that did the trick, weird, I tried that before but got an error but now it works  BTW are you from the EatTheBlocks discord ?

Comment: Awesome! Could you mark this as the accepted answer? Yes, I found your question in the EatTheBlocks discord.

Comment: Ok and write your eth address for the bounty of 15 USD, Im a man of my word 

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
import token_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/FixedSupplyToken.json'
```

I'm guessing your local webserver is rooted where your HTML page is.  Hence, any attempt to pull content outside of the web server root (i.e. from the `..` folder) is going to get declined.

Reload your page with the the F12 tools running showing network traffic. I suspect you're going to get a 404 result when the page attempts to do a `GET ../../build/contracts/FixedSupplyToken.json`

Hence, `token_artifacts` undefined, and everything else created off of it is also undefined.

The quick hack is to move FixedSupplyToken.json into your web root and adjust the import statement appropriately.

The other issue I had with my python web server with that even after I had moved the json to the web root, the `python -m http.server` thing I was running was returning a mime type in the `Content-Type` header rejected by the javascript importer.  The quick hack I did was just to paste the json declaration into a .js file and give it a variable assignment such as the following:

```
window.FizzBuzzContract =    // added this line
{
  "contractName": "FizzBuzz",
  "abi": [...
```

Comment: Hi...so Ive been playing around with this one today, tried to move the FixedSupplyToken.json to webroot but got the same undefined error as before , then tried to move it around again to some other folder  and got the "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../FixedSupplyToken.json" " so i guess it was in the right folder and it does import it, or I would get the module not found error before? Hmm was thinking, do you think that maybe the truffle-contract could be the problem, because it is obsolete and replaced now with the @truffle/contract ? :/  thx